# Put something manually into the header of the current page

Tags: header-footer

Is it possible to write something custom into the header of the current page for example like this pseudocode

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\thispageheader[R]{My Text}  %Displays only this in the header
\newpage
\thispageheader[R]{Another Text} %Displays only this in the header
\newpage 
\thispageheader[L]{Just another Text on the left} %Displays only this in the header
\end{document}
```

It's important for me that everything is done locally. I don't want to define different fancy header styles globally for each manual header text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you are willing to define the pages in a group, it is relatively easy

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\lhead{\headerL}
\chead{\headerC}
\rhead{\headerR}
\def\headerL{}
\def\headerC{}
\def\headerR{}
\newcommand{\thispageheader}[2][R]{\expandafter\def\csname header#1\endcsname{#2}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

{\thispageheader[R]{My Text}  %Displays only this in the header
\lipsum[1]
\newpage}
{\thispageheader[R]{Another Text} %Displays only this in the header
\lipsum[1]
\newpage}
{\thispageheader[L]{Just another Text on the left} %Displays only this in the header
\lipsum[1]\newpage}
\end{document}
```

It is not really clear how you want the headers to behave outside the groups. Maybe something like

```
\newcommand{\resetheaders}{\def\headerL{}\def\headerC{}\def\headerR{}}
```